# Glob matching file paths with multiple periods

Tags: glob

I am trying to match files which have a number of periods in the filename, including the extension, using globs.

```bash
ls /path/to/my/example.file.txt
ls /path/to/my/file.txt
ls /path/to/my-example.file.txt
ls /path/to/my.example.file.txt
ls /path/which/is/longer/to/my/example.file.txt
ls /path/which/is/even/longer/to/my/example.file.txt
```

I tried using the following;

```bash
ls /path/**/*.txt
```

but I am only getting some matches. It appears that if the file has more than a single period, `*.txt` will not match.

I tried something like the following, but it doesn't really work, and I imagine there is a much cleaner way to accomplish this.

```bash
ls /path/**/[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*.txt
ls /path/**/**.txt
ls /path/**/*.*.txt     # Doesn't work for files with a single period
```

Use of `ls` and paths is for example only.

I am open to the idea the underlying program may not implement globbing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I was passing the glob to another program and it was being expanded in bash before being read by the program

```bash
program '/path/**/*.txt'   # works as expected
```